# Django Rest Framework Integity Error Catch

Tags: django, rest, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework I did the seriailizers, viewsets and routers approach. Whenever I POST with an intentional error in the API view of django rest framework it throws an Integrity Error. Is there a way to try and catch the errors like if there is no errors in the data just proceed to save however if there are errors throw a JSON Response with the list of errors like:

```
[{'section':'This field can not be blank', 'first_name':'This field can not be blank', 'middle_name':'This field can not be blank', 'last_name':'This field can not be blank'}]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
# class AuditTable(models.Model):
#   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # test_field = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, default=None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        full_name = "%s %s %s" % (self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . models import *

class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ('name', )

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('section', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name' )
```

viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from . serializers import *
from . models import *

class SectionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Section.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

routers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

from . viewsets import *

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'students', StudentViewSet)
router.register(r'sections', SectionViewSet)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from . import views
from . routers import router

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='testing_sample_index' ),
    url(r'^restful-form/$', views.web_service_form, name='testing_sample_web_service' ),

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: What are you going to put into your required fields on saving if there was no input? Some default values?

Comment: Just blank, I intentionally did that to get a response of serializer errors

Answer (score 7):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299085/2996101), the solution would be:

viewsets.py

```
from django.db import IntegrityError    # Import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException  #Import APIException
from . serializers import *
from . models import *

class SectionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Section.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as exc:
            raise APIException(detail=exc)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have an `IntegrityError` then your models aren't up to date with your database.

You should set uniqueness constraint to match your DB scheme.

Note that DRF can validate against unique constraints with the [UniqueValidator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator)

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, at least nowadays: you can get an integrity error when, for instance, trying to create an object with a PositiveIntegerField, passing a negative value to it.

Answer (score 4):

The default `CreateMixin` implementation [raises an exception](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L20) on any validation error. So you could write your own custom mixin...

```
class VerboseCreateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Create a model instance and return either created object or the validation errors.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

...and then use it in your `ViewSet`:

```
class SectionViewSet(VerboseCreateModelMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Section.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer
```

Comment: Thank You , You saved my life!! :))

Answer (score 1):

There is a better (in my opinion) solution:
Django Rest Framework has a [EXCEPTION_HANDLER](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) that allows to customly handle exceptions not handled by default by it.

So, you have to:

1. Configure DRF to specify which EXCEPTION_HANDLER to use. Got to your settings and add this:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'applications.utils.exception_handler'
    }
```

2. Write the exception_handler function logic in the specified place (applications.utils in this case, but you can change that):

```
def exception_handler(exc, context):
    """
    Handle Django ValidationError as an accepted exception by DRF.
    For the parameters, see ``exception_handler``
    """
    if isinstance(exc, IntegrityError):
        exc = DRFValidationError(detail=exc)
    return drf_exception_handler(exc, context)
```

Now, whenever an IntegrityError is raised that DRF's serializer doesn't handle, this function will translate it to DRFValidationError which will be properly handled returning a 400 error with a proper data.