# DRf, handle unhandled exception

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When using DRF, Django's ValueError (django.core.exceptions) and IntegrityError (django.db) is not handled.

DRF's `def exception_handler` has exception handling code for (APIException, Http404, PermissionDenied)

Below is a code for `Http404`

```
 elif isinstance(exc, Http404):
     msg = _('Not found.')
     data = {'detail': six.text_type(msg)}

     set_rollback()
     return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

So I can create my custom exception handler as

```
 def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
     # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
     # to get the standard error response.
     response = exception_handler(exc, context)

     if isinstance(exc, ValidationError) or isinstance(exc, IntegrityError):
         data = {
             'errors': str(exc)
         }
         set_rollback()   # not sure about this line
         response = Response(data, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

     return response
```

I'm not sure about the purpose of `set_rollback()` line in the code, and not sure if I'm safe with this code.

Comment: Just a side note: you can use tuple of classes as second arg to `isinstance`. `isinstance(exc, (ValidationError, IntegrityError))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `IntegrityError`  and `ValueError` aren't handled by default in DRF is because they need to be handled in a case by case basis. So writing a generic exception handler like what you are trying to do here probably isn't the right way.

For example, some `IntegrityErrors` can probably be just ignored, but some like that happens in the middle of a fund transfer cannot be. So better to try something like this:

```
def create(self, request):
    try :
        return super(MyViewSet, self).create(request)
    except IntergrityError:
        # your decision here how to handle it.
        raise APIException(detail='Custom message')
```