# Django rest framwork - how to prevent 1062, "Duplicate entry"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

at my Django application (DRF only), I'm trying to create a new object where one of the fields is setup like this:

```
 resource_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Resource Name", blank=False, null=False, max_length=50, unique=True)
```

If I now try to create an Object with the same resource_name twice, I'm always running into the following exception:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry
> 'test_ressource123' for key 'resource_name'")

Is there any good solution that I can apply to all kinds of these situations?
Would be awesome to simply make the API response that the object already exists, kinda strange that this is not already a built-in of DRF. Can I maybe overwrite the def create function call of the serializer ? Any good advice welcome.

Comment: You can write validation in your serializer class.

Comment: I already came across this Idea, but this is some annoying if you have a lot of models, as you have to access every potential unique field for all you serializers, I hoped that this can be handeld some more general with a decorator or so that fetches the instance but this still won't solve the question when to check which model.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should develop a serializer for each model to understand how you work with each one. Later you can forget about this "common" solution and look for a bug for a long time.

Nevertheless, I see two approaches to achieve that behavior.

##### Overriden `ModelViewSet`

We can redefine the `create` method of default `ModelViewSet` and then inherit your `ModelViewSet`s from this class. Like this:

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

class SupressIntegrityErrorModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise APIException(detail=str(e), code=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896953/12914274).

##### DRF [custom exception handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Firstly you need to make a `custom_exception_handler` method; DRF documentation suggests making it in `<application-directory>/utils.py`:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    if type(exc).__name__ == 'IntegrityError':
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(str(e))

    return exception_handler(exc, context)
```

Then you have to set `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` in your `settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to add `UniqueValidator` to your serializer.

```
resource_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=YourModel.objects.all())], requierd=False)
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a different error status code than 400 for this UniqueValidator validator? I would like to show a 409 error instead.